# Unintentionally the same data records in the UI list more than once

Tags: c#, wpf, list, events, duplicates

I have a somewhat unusual problem.

I wrote a damage meter for a game and have the problem, if I attack 2 opponents at the same time in the game, I am shown several times in the list.

To get the data from the game, I use PhotonParser, which reads out the network data.
(First of all, it's nothing illegal.)

[image]

```
public class AlbionPackageParser : PhotonParser
{
    private readonly HealthUpdateEventHandler HealthUpdateEventHandler;

    public AlbionPackageParser(TrackingController trackingController, MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel)
    {
        HealthUpdateEventHandler = new HealthUpdateEventHandler(trackingController);
    }
    
    protected override void OnEvent(byte code, Dictionary<byte, object> parameters)
    {
        var eventCode = ParseEventCode(parameters);

        if (eventCode == EventCodes.Unused)
        {
            return;
        }

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            switch (eventCode)
            {
                case EventCodes.HealthUpdate:
                    await HealthUpdateEventHandlerAsync(parameters).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    return;
            }
        });
    }
    
    private static EventCodes ParseEventCode(IReadOnlyDictionary<byte, object> parameters)
    {
        if (!parameters.TryGetValue(252, out var value))
        {
            return EventCodes.Unused;
        }

        return (EventCodes)Enum.ToObject(typeof(EventCodes), value);
    }

    private async Task HealthUpdateEventHandlerAsync(Dictionary<byte, object> parameters)
    {
        var value = new HealthUpdateEvent(parameters);
        await HealthUpdateEventHandler.OnActionAsync(value);
    }
}
```

```
public class HealthUpdateEventHandler
{
    private readonly TrackingController _trackingController;

    public HealthUpdateEventHandler(TrackingController trackingController)
    {
        _trackingController = trackingController;
    }

    public async Task OnActionAsync(HealthUpdateEvent value)
    {
        await _trackingController.CombatController.AddDamageAsync(value.ObjectId, value.CauserId, value.HealthChange, value.NewHealthValue);
    }
}
```

```
public class HealthUpdateEvent
{
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()?.DeclaringType);
    public long CauserId;
    public int CausingSpellType;
    public EffectOrigin EffectOrigin;
    public EffectType EffectType;
    public double HealthChange;
    public double NewHealthValue;

    public long ObjectId;
    public GameTimeStamp TimeStamp;

    public HealthUpdateEvent(Dictionary<byte, object> parameters)
    {
        ConsoleManager.WriteLineForNetworkHandler(GetType().Name, parameters);

        try
        {
            if (parameters.ContainsKey(0))
            {
                ObjectId = parameters[0].ObjectToLong() ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }

            if (parameters.ContainsKey(1))
            {
                TimeStamp = new GameTimeStamp(parameters[1].ObjectToLong() ?? 0);
            }

            if (parameters.ContainsKey(2))
            {
                HealthChange = parameters[2].ObjectToDouble();
            }

            if (parameters.ContainsKey(3))
            {
                NewHealthValue = parameters[3].ObjectToDouble();
            }

            if (parameters.ContainsKey(4))
            {
                EffectType = (EffectType) (parameters[4] as byte? ?? 0);
            }

            if (parameters.ContainsKey(5))
            {
                EffectOrigin = (EffectOrigin) (parameters[5] as byte? ?? 0);
            }

            if (parameters.ContainsKey(6))
            {
                CauserId = parameters[6].ObjectToLong() ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }

            if (parameters.ContainsKey(7))
            {
                CausingSpellType = parameters[7].ObjectToShort();
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
        {
            ConsoleManager.WriteLineForError(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()?.DeclaringType, ex);
            Log.Error(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()?.DeclaringType, ex);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ConsoleManager.WriteLineForError(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()?.DeclaringType, e);
            Log.Error(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()?.DeclaringType, e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Most important file:**

```
public class CombatController
{
    public async Task AddDamageAsync(long objectId, long causerId, double healthChange, double newHealthValue)
    {
        if (!IsDamageMeterActive || objectId == causerId)
        {
            return;
        }

        var gameObject = _trackingController?.EntityController?.GetEntity(causerId);

        if (gameObject?.Value == null
            || gameObject.Value.Value?.ObjectType != GameObjectType.Player
            || !_trackingController.EntityController.IsUserInParty(gameObject.Value.Value.Name)
            )
        {
            return;
        }

        if (GetHealthChangeType(healthChange) == HealthChangeType.Damage)
        {
            var damageChangeValue = (int)Math.Round(healthChange.ToPositiveFromNegativeOrZero(), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
            if (damageChangeValue <= 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            gameObject.Value.Value.Damage += damageChangeValue;
        }

        if (GetHealthChangeType(healthChange) == HealthChangeType.Heal)
        {
            var healChangeValue = healthChange;
            if (healChangeValue <= 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (IsMaxHealthReached(objectId, newHealthValue))
            {
                return;
            }

            gameObject.Value.Value.Heal += (int)Math.Round(healChangeValue, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        }

        if (gameObject.Value.Value?.CombatStart == null)
        {
            gameObject.Value.Value.CombatStart = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
        
        if (await IsUiUpdateAllowedAsync() && !IsUiUpdateActive)
        {
            await UpdateDamageMeterUiAsync(_mainWindowViewModel.DamageMeter, _trackingController.EntityController.GetAllEntities());
        }
    }
    
    private static bool IsUiUpdateActive;

    public async Task UpdateDamageMeterUiAsync(AsyncObservableCollection<DamageMeterFragment> damageMeter, List<KeyValuePair<Guid, PlayerGameObject>> entities)
    {
        IsUiUpdateActive = true;

        var highestDamage = entities.GetHighestDamage();
        var highestHeal = entities.GetHighestHeal();
        _trackingController.EntityController.DetectUsedWeapon();

        foreach (var healthChangeObject in entities)
        {
            if (_mainWindow?.Dispatcher == null || healthChangeObject.Value?.UserGuid == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var fragment = damageMeter.ToList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.CauserGuid == healthChangeObject.Value.UserGuid);
            if (fragment != null)
            {
                await UpdateDamageMeterFragmentAsync(fragment, healthChangeObject, entities, highestDamage, highestHeal).ConfigureAwait(true);
            }
            else
            {
                await AddDamageMeterFragmentAsync(damageMeter, healthChangeObject, entities, highestDamage, highestHeal).ConfigureAwait(true);
            }

            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => _mainWindowViewModel.SetDamageMeterSort());
        }

        if (HasDamageMeterDupes(_mainWindowViewModel.DamageMeter))
        {
            await RemoveDuplicatesAsync(_mainWindowViewModel.DamageMeter);
        }

        IsUiUpdateActive = false;
    }

    private async Task UpdateDamageMeterFragmentAsync(DamageMeterFragment fragment, KeyValuePair<Guid, PlayerGameObject> healthChangeObject, List<KeyValuePair<Guid, PlayerGameObject>> entities, long highestDamage, long highestHeal)
    {
        var itemInfo = await SetItemInfoIfSlotTypeMainHandAsync(fragment.CauserMainHand, healthChangeObject.Value?.CharacterEquipment?.MainHand).ConfigureAwait(false);
        fragment.CauserMainHand = itemInfo;

        // Damage
        if (healthChangeObject.Value?.Damage > 0)
        {
            fragment.DamageInPercent = (double)healthChangeObject.Value.Damage / highestDamage * 100;
            fragment.Damage = (long)healthChangeObject.Value?.Damage;
        }

        if (healthChangeObject.Value?.Dps != null)
        {
            fragment.Dps = healthChangeObject.Value.Dps;
        }

        // Heal
        if (healthChangeObject.Value?.Heal > 0)
        {
            fragment.HealInPercent = (double)healthChangeObject.Value.Heal / highestHeal * 100;
            fragment.Heal = (long)healthChangeObject.Value?.Heal;
        }


        if (healthChangeObject.Value?.Hps != null)
        {
            fragment.Hps = healthChangeObject.Value.Hps;
        }

        // Generally
        if (healthChangeObject.Value != null)
        {
            fragment.DamagePercentage = entities.GetDamagePercentage(healthChangeObject.Value.Damage);
            fragment.HealPercentage = entities.GetHealPercentage(healthChangeObject.Value.Heal);

            _trackingController.EntityController.SetPartyCircleColor(healthChangeObject.Value.UserGuid, itemInfo?.FullItemInformation?.CategoryId);
        }
    }

    private async Task AddDamageMeterFragmentAsync(AsyncObservableCollection<DamageMeterFragment> damageMeter, KeyValuePair<Guid, PlayerGameObject> healthChangeObject,
        List<KeyValuePair<Guid, PlayerGameObject>> entities, long highestDamage, long highestHeal)
    {
        if (healthChangeObject.Value == null
            || (double.IsNaN(healthChangeObject.Value.Damage) && double.IsNaN(healthChangeObject.Value.Heal))
            || (healthChangeObject.Value.Damage <= 0 && healthChangeObject.Value.Heal <= 0))
        {
            return;
        }

        var mainHandItem = ItemController.GetItemByIndex(healthChangeObject.Value?.CharacterEquipment?.MainHand ?? 0);
        var itemInfo = await SetItemInfoIfSlotTypeMainHandAsync(mainHandItem, healthChangeObject.Value?.CharacterEquipment?.MainHand);

        var damageMeterFragment = new DamageMeterFragment
        {
            CauserGuid = healthChangeObject.Value.UserGuid,
            Damage = healthChangeObject.Value.Damage,
            Dps = healthChangeObject.Value.Dps,
            DamageInPercent = (double)healthChangeObject.Value.Damage / highestDamage * 100,
            DamagePercentage = entities.GetDamagePercentage(healthChangeObject.Value.Damage),

            Heal = healthChangeObject.Value.Heal,
            Hps = healthChangeObject.Value.Hps,
            HealInPercent = (double)healthChangeObject.Value.Heal / highestHeal * 100,
            HealPercentage = entities.GetHealPercentage(healthChangeObject.Value.Heal),

            Name = healthChangeObject.Value.Name,
            CauserMainHand = itemInfo
        };

        damageMeter.Init(Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke);
        damageMeter.Add(damageMeterFragment);

        _trackingController.EntityController.SetPartyCircleColor(healthChangeObject.Value.UserGuid, itemInfo?.FullItemInformation?.CategoryId);
    }

    // Try 1
    private bool IsUiUpdateAllowed(int waitTimeInSeconds = 1)
    {
        var currentDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var difference = currentDateTime.Subtract(_lastDamageUiUpdate);
        if (difference.Seconds >= waitTimeInSeconds && !IsUiUpdateActive)
        {
            _lastDamageUiUpdate = currentDateTime;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    // Try 2
    private async Task<bool> IsUiUpdateAllowedAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(true);
        if (_updateReadyCounter++ < 2)
        {
            return false;
        }

        _updateReadyCounter = 0;
        return true;
    }
}
```

In the last class "CombatController" I am currently trying to get the problem under control.

The "UpdateDamageMeterUiAsync ()" method should only be triggered once if IsUiUpdateAllowedAsync () is true.

Nevertheless, "UpdateDamageMeterUiAsync ()" is always triggered 2-3 times at the same time, which is why multiple entries are created. All other lists are fine, only the UI object "AsyncObservableCollection  _mainWindowViewModel.DamageMeter" has the problem.

Does anyone have any idea how I can tackle the problem?

Comment: As I look through the code. Even though the UpdateDamageMeterUIAsync() is trigged multiple times.

`var fragment = damageMeter.ToList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.CauserGuid == healthChangeObject.Value.UserGuid);
            if (fragment != null)`

this piece of code should return a valid guid after the 1st update. So should result in only an update of the existing fragment but not add a new fragment.

Comment: There is really not information to understand your code. If you have debugged your code and can ensure that the data source is only returning player data once than why don't you debug your code properly? What I can assume from reviewing the code is that you are updating the collection concurrently without providing a synchroniszation mechanism. Given that OnEvent is called multiple succesive times, then you create a concurrency scenario: since Task.Run is not awaited, you start new parallel background threads on each call.

Comment: I don't see any reason for your Tas.Run call at all. Here, Task.Run only wraps an already async method, which is a bad smell. Remove the Task.Run and simply await HealthUpdateEventHandlerAsync(). Give it a shot. I assume your issue will be resolved.

Comment: @BionicCode thank you, this was the issue.